# Got stuck at /dev/sdaX: clean (accidentally removed display manager?)

Tags: boot, 17.10, display-manager

I needed to free up some memory by removing a couple of i.m.o. unnecessary running stuff on my working **Ubuntu 17.10**… since I don't use `snapd` `evolution-*` `gnome-calendar`, I purged them and after reboot I have no display anymore and just see the `/dev/sdaX: clean, …`

I tried to reinstall the stuff above in CLI `(ttyl)` and also `apt update` and `apt dist-upgrade` and `grub-install` but none of them helped actually. The common found solution as booting without graphic `nomodeset` and install Intel graphic drivers didn't work too (nothing more than a blank Ubuntu purple colored screen appears… in addition there's no intel graphic drivers for 17.10 yet)

Does anyone know the solution?

PS: I'm not sure if removing the packages named above really made the problem.

Comment: fyi: Evolution-* [evolution-data-server] is used & needed by GNOME [to show anything on your screen], which is not related to the evolution-MUA (mail user agent or mail app), so it could be your problem.  https://projects-old.gnome.org/evolution/arch.shtml

Comment: @guiverc good to know but I installed back "evolution*" and the problem persisted. What else could I remove from standards installation of 17.10 to get some ram free? Alone gnome-shell is taking more than 5.5% as shown in htop

Comment: `evolution` is the mail user agent/mail program.  `evolution-data-server` gnome needs to put info to your screen/displays.  I'd hope `sudo apt install evolution-data-server` would also pull in the necessary other files you've removed (evolution-data-server-common, evolution-data-server-.... etc).  you'll also likely have to restart the display services (eg. gdm3)

Comment: as for getting more ram - the easiest would be using another DEsktop.

Comment: I would like to get back to unity but keeping some features in current version e.g. window-manager (which lets me resize two side-by-side windows proportionally). Even though this last named feature if gnome is not so important, is it possible to replace the desktop in 17.10 or it's gonna be a dirty job?

Comment: adding other DEsktops is real easy. `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop` will add XFCE or xubuntu to your machine (its light; not as light as lubuntu but more to my liking).  MATE is a little lighter too (than GNOME, KDE or Unity), but not as light as XFCE or LXDE

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it with unity first... I already have 8 GB of RAM and with intellij, Chrome, my MySQL and apache service I have almost ¾ of my RAM occupied. Seems the 8GB is the new initial specs for developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments

`sudo apt install evolution-data-server`

which I'm hoping should also restore other needed GNOME packages (evolution-data-server-common, ...)

evolution-data-server is used by GNOME in writing data to the screen and thus is needed.  It is NOT part of the Evolution MUA (mail user agent) or Evolution mail program (which too is part of the GNOME project, but not part of GNOME Shell)